# Cannot find module '@semantic-ui-react/craco-less' when install semantic ui theming

Tags: node.js, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm building a semantic-ui project with theming. Here is their tutorial https://react.semantic-ui.com/theming

The problem I met is, I followed all the way of its operation, and I finally got

> Error: Cannot find module '@semantic-ui-react/craco-less'

error. I promise I have installed all required package, include this.

```
{
  "name": "sora",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.21",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "craco eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.3",
    "@semantic-ui-react/craco-less": "^2.0.0",
    "semantic-ui-less": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

craco.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [{ plugin: require('@semantic-ui-react/craco-less') }],
}
```

But it still have an error when I run yarn start

```
yarn run v1.22.17
$ craco start
(node:7648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module '@semantic-ui-react/craco-less'
Require stack:
- /home/cat/WebstormProjects/sora/craco.config.js
- /home/cat/WebstormProjects/sora/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/loaders.js
- /home/cat/WebstormProjects/sora/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/ExplorerBase.js
- /home/cat/WebstormProjects/sora/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/Explorer.js
- /home/cat/WebstormProjects/sora/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/index.js
- /home/cat/WebstormProjects/sora/node_modules/@craco/craco/lib/config.js
- /home/cat/WebstormProjects/sora/node_modules/@craco/craco/scripts/start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/cat/WebstormProjects/sora/craco.config.js:2:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:7648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:7648) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Done in 0.20s.
```